# How to access X:Y value of XML file in twig.

Tags: php, xml, twig

```
<item rdf:about="http://test.com/test.html">
<title>test</title>
<link>http://test.com</link>
<description>
These are description for 
</description>
<dc:creator>amosaic</dc:creator>
<dc:date>2014-01-16T18:15:03+09:00</dc:date>
<dc:subject>keyword</dc:subject>
<content:encoded>
```

I have xml files like this.

I got xml file and convert into the object

```
$xmlobj = simplexml_load_string($file)
```

then in twig

I can access

```
{{ xmlobj.title }}
{{ xmlobj.link }}
```

But I would like to access dc:date data as well.

```
{{xmlobj.dc:date}}
```

doesn't work.

Could you help me?

Comment: Have you tried `{{ xmlobj.children('dc', true).date }}` ?

Comment: glad it worked. I hope you understand what it does and why it works,

Comment: ya,I will keep learning....